# Can't output a message using angular 2 data binding

Tags: angular

I can't seem to display the text using message: Message = new Message(), it just comes out as blank and I'm also getting console errors saying can't read property 'content' of undefined.

My current message.model.ts:

```
export class Message {
 content: string;
 username: string;
 messageId?: string;
 userId?: string;

 constructor(content: string, username: string, messageId?: string, userId?: string) {
   this.content = content;
   this.username = username;
   this.messageId = messageId;
   this.userId = userId;
 }
}
```

message.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from './message.model';

@Component ({
 selector: 'app-message',
 templateUrl: './message.component.html',
 styles: [`
   .author {
     display: inline-block;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 12px;
     width: 80%;
   }
   .config {
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: right;
     font-size: 12px;
     width: 19%;
   }
 `]

})
export class MessageComponent {
 @Input() message: Message;
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from './messages/message.model';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
 message: Message = new Message("this is the content", "Some guy");
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
     <app-message [message]="message"></app-message>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

message.component.html

```
<article class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{ message.content }}
  </div>
  <footer class="panel-footer">
    <div class="author">
      {{ message.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="config">
      <a href="#" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</article>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './messages/message.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MessageComponent
    ],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, MessageComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: This code should work

Comment: Maybe you should post app.module, too

Comment: I'm seriously confused on what I got wrong as well. I noticed that it started not displaying the message right when I added the @Input part.

Comment: Try recreating problem on stackblitz and maybe you will find the cause

Comment: @turo added the app.module

Comment: That was the key) `bootstrap` property

Comment: yes, MessageComponent doesn't belong there

Comment: Ha! That worked! Any chance I could get an explanation as to why that somehow fixed the issue? I'm really new to angular.

Comment: with bootstrap MessageComponent gets created to early, without beeing demanded in app.component.html

Comment: I see. That's makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot @turo

Answer (score 0):

The passed `message` parameter will be assigned after the view is created. You can enforce using `*ngIf` to let the template show only if the message is assigned

```
<article *ngIf="message" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{ message.content }}
  </div>
  <footer class="panel-footer">
    <div class="author">
      {{ message.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="config">
      <a href="#" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Also you can write your class in short

```
export class Message {

   constructor(public content: string, 
               public username: string, 
               public messageId?: string, 
               public userId?: string) { }
}
```

Comment: adding *ngIf somehow gets rid of the errors, but I'm still wondering why I can't display the static strings I set on

export class AppComponent {
 message: Message = new Message("this is the content", "Some guy");
}

Also, tried doing the shorthand method for the model and still no luck :/

Comment: Because the template is created, then in the `ngOnInit` you get the `@Input` initialized

Comment: What about short class syntax - this is just a better way